# Inline PythonScript Azure Pipelines task in external file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am developing a Azure task template, and I have a large .py file that I want to be executed in one step

```yaml
  - task: PythonScript@0
    displayName: 'Run a Python script'
    inputs:
      scriptSource: inline
      script: |
        ... really long python code
```

It's possible to store the code in another file, at the same level of the `yml` template, and consume it from there? Or what would be the best approach to keep the template clean?

I know that it's possible to use `scriptSource`

```yaml
  - task: PythonScript@0
    displayName: 'Run a Python script'
    inputs:
      scriptSource: 'filePath'
      scriptPath: 'my_python.py'
      arguments: '${{ parameters.my_param }}'
```

But as the template is in another repository than the repository ran in the pipeline, I don't think that I can reach that `my_python.py` without downloading it with a wget, or cloning, or doing additional steps. I am right?

Regards!

Comment: Hi @Del . Is there any update about this ticket? If Krzysztof Madej's answer could solve this issue, you may consider accepting it as answer. This will be helpful to other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a template from another repo you need to define [repository source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories) like here:

```
# Repo: Contoso/LinuxProduct
# File: azure-pipelines.yml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: github
      name: Contoso/BuildTemplates

steps:
- template: common.yml@templates  # Template reference
```

Once you have you need to just checkout this repo:

```
# Repo: Contoso/LinuxProduct
# File: azure-pipelines.yml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: github
      name: Contoso/BuildTemplates

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: templates #this download whole repo
- template: common.yml@templates  # Template reference
```

Now you need to figure out where it is [downloaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path) ;)

> Multiple repositories: If you have multiple checkout steps in your job, your source code is checked out into directories named after the repositories as a subfolder of s in `(Agent.BuildDirectory)`. If (Agent.BuildDirectory) is `C:\agent\_work\1` and your repositories are named tools and code, your code is checked out to `C:\agent\_work\1\s\tools` and `C:\agent\_work\1\s\code`.

So if you have script in `scripts` folder in `templates` repo you will find it in `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\templates\scripts\script.py`.

So then you can use it like this:

```yaml
  - task: PythonScript@0
    displayName: 'Run a Python script'
    inputs:
      scriptSource: 'filePath'
      scriptPath: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\templates\scripts\script.py'
      arguments: '${{ parameters.my_param }}'
```

Comment: the OP is asking to have his template refer to a python script which lives in the template repo ... your bottom most code snippet suggests code you put into the client pipeline because you mention templates which you define only in client pipeline ... however the OP wants to avoid the client pipeline from seeing that underlying python script .... goal of OP is to hide inside the template all dealings with the python ... please update